# Variations of $e^{ \frac{-2}{x}} - \frac{x-1}{x+1}$

Tags: calculus

I have to study the variations of the function
$$f : x \mapsto e^{ \frac{-2}{x}} - \frac{x-1}{x+1}$$
over $]0,+\infty[$.

The derivative gaves me something more complicated:
$$ f'(x) = \frac{2}{x^2}e^{ \frac{-2}{x}} - \frac{2}{(x+1)^2}
$$

Comment: Are you sure 1) you have the right equation, 2) you've written down the question as it appears in your assignment?

Comment: What do you mean by "the variations of a function"?

Comment: i mean increasing or decreasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
e^{2/x}=1+{2\over x}+{2\over x^2}+{4\over3x^3}+\cdots>1+{2\over x}+{1\over x^2}=\left({x+1\over x}\right)^2
$$
so $x^2e^{2/x}>(x+1)^2$, so $(2/x^2)e^{-2/x}<2/(x+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall x>0\quad f'(x)<0$$ because
$$\frac{e^{-2/x}}{x^2}<(x+1)^2$$
i.e.
$$\frac{e^{-2/x}}{x^2}<\frac1{(x+1)^2}$$
i.e.
$$\frac{x+1}x<e^{1/x},$$
since
$$\forall t\in\Bbb R\quad e^t>1+t.$$